# How can I login with several users at the same time using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

So I have a csv file called users.csv and it is something like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

In csv data set config I have

```
Filename: users.csv
Variable names: username
```

And in User Defined Variables I have:

```
username
```

In my recorded test I have a request to /login.html with parameters:

```
app_user ${username}
```

I have tried in Thread Group this:

```
Number of Threads(users): 3
```

However I only see that user1 is logged in when I execute my test.

How can I make all of them login in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to make your login requests concurrent.

Add it as a child of your login request. It'll pause all threads until threshold specified in `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` input will be reached.

Remember to provide enough threads in Thread Group elsewise your test will be hanging infinitely.